# Completing the cal, sum the vlookup value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

As you can see that the value in column Amount in the first image is manually put into it. I would like to use VBA to do it automatically.

**Table B546789 is one of the worker:**

[image: IMG1 - Table B546789 is one of the worker]

**PriceList shown the amount of each code item:**

[image: IMG2 - PriceList shown the amount of each code item]

Code:

```
Sub FINDSAL()
    Dim E_name() As String
    Dim Sal As String
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PriceList")
    SourceString = Worksheets("B546789").Range("B2").Value
    E_name() = Split(SourceString, ",")
    Sal = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(E_name, Worksheets("PriceList").Range("A2:B7"), 2, False)
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share the code?

Comment: Sub FINDSAL()
Dim E_name() As String

Dim Sal As String

SourceString = Worksheets("B546789").Range("B2").Value
E_name() = Split(SourceString, ",")
Sal = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(E_name, Worksheets("PriceList").Range("A2:B7"), 2, False)
End Sub

I know that is not yet complete, but i have no idea how to do it. please help on this matter, seems complicated than vlookup as multiple sroucestring.

Comment: thank you Ashleedawg for edit the thread.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Here's a video to get you started with `VLookUp`: **[Office.com: Excel 2013 training VLOOKUP — When and how to use it](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/video-vlookup-when-and-how-to-use-it-9a86157a-5542-4148-a536-724823014785)** ...Please take a few minutes to check out the [tour] and there are also important tips in "[ask]" as well as tips about **providing examples** at "[mcve]".  We like to see that some effort has been made in finding a solution before asking for help (on a _specific_ problem), so please includes details about what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

A simple SUMPRODUCT should do this.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND(F$2:F$8, B2)), G$2:G$8)
```

[image]

VBA code:

```
Dim a As Long, b As Long, ttl As Double
Dim vals As Variant, pc As Variant
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PriceList")

With Worksheets("B546789")
    For b = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        ttl = 0
        vals = Split(.Cells(b, "B").Value2, Chr(44))
        For a = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
            pc = Application.Match(vals(a), sh.Columns(1), 0)
            If Not IsError(pc) Then
                ttl = ttl + sh.Cells(pc, "B").Value2
            End If
        Next a
        .Cells(b, "C") = ttl
    Next b
End With
```

Comment: Thanks Jeeped for your help, but when some value in B column which is double. like "IN,IN" only shown not sum.

Comment: In that case you will have to split the string and loop through the elements of the array. I look forward to seeing your own effort on this.

Comment: Can you give me more hints, since i only find split function on VBA, and for loop is more difficult to use.

Answer (score 0):

Any hints that when i put below code to VBA ThisWorkbook, work fine. But assign this Marco to a button, it will crash when i run. do you know why?

Sub test()

```
Dim a As Long, b As Long, ttl As Double, ttlerror As String
Dim vals As Variant, pc As Variant
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim WshtNames As Variant
Dim WshtNameCrnt As Variant


Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PriceList")
WshtNames = Array("B54546", "B87987")

For Each WshtNameCrnt In WshtNames
With Worksheets(WshtNameCrnt)
    For b = 8 To [D8].End(xlDown).Row
        ttl = 0
    ttlerror = ""
        vals = Split(.Cells(b, "D").Value2, Chr(44))
        For a = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
            pc = Application.Match(vals(a), sh.Columns(1), 0)
            If Not IsError(pc) Then
                ttl = ttl + sh.Cells(pc, "B").Value2
            End If
        Next a
        .Cells(b, "E") = ttl
    .Cells(b, "F") = ttlerror
    Next b
End With
Next WshtNameCrnt
```

End Sub

the issue maybe related to this "For b = 8 To [D8].End(xlDown).Row", it only happen when i use the button feature.
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JBk2.png)

Comment: i just want from the D8 to end of the designed table.